# Преобразование кодировки /u в utf-8

Tags: кодировка, php

Возникла проблема: русские буквы из формы приходят в виде /u####.

- страница имеет charset="utf-8"
- скрипты в utf-8
- БД в utf8_general_ci
- скрипт устанавливает в запросе к БД `SET NAMES 'utf8'`

И тем не менее, в базу уходят вопросики.
Подскажите, как с таким бороться?

Comment: без примера не особо понятно..
php ловит в место букв - \u#### (код символа в unicode)? либо всё таки /u####, а в базу просто ?????? в итоге?

Comment: Да, код символа в unicode \u0444\u0444\u0444 например

Comment: А каким образом данные из формы передаются? Возможно - из формы передаётся JSON?

Answer (score 1):

Была такая же проблема, причину не нашел, конвертировал, функцию нашел 
[здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1805802/php-convert-unicode-codepoint-to-utf-8)